# How to create a graph with multiple nested facets horizontally and vertically?

Tags: r, ggplot2, nested, facet, geom-bar

Below is a simplified version of my data. I want to plot the Means using vertical bars with `ggplot() + geom_bar`. There are a few things I want to do.

- I want to separate the data where I have the data grouped vertically (=side by side/beside each other/in columns) according to Vfront (all "front" data on left, all "back" data on right).
- I also want to separate the data where I have the data grouped horizontally (on top of each other/in rows) according to Manner (all "Stop" on top row, all "Fric" on bottom row).
- Additionally, I want to have the different MedDors grouped per Target (in the NA, cor, incor, X order).

```
Target  Manner  Vfront  MedDor  Mean
p       Stop    front   NA      0.60
p       Stop    back    NA      0.59
p       Stop    front   cor     0.58
p       Stop    back    cor     0.56
p       Stop    front   incor   0.52
p       Stop    back    incor   0.52
p       Stop    front   X       0.24
p       Stop    back    X       0.52
b       Stop    front   NA      0.42
b       Stop    back    NA      0.39
b       Stop    front   cor     0.37
b       Stop    back    cor     0.42
b       Stop    front   incor   0.36
b       Stop    back    incor   0.33
b       Stop    front   X       0.14
b       Stop    back    X       0.39
f       Fric    front   NA      0.27
f       Fric    back    NA      0.23
f       Fric    front   cor     0.19
f       Fric    back    cor     0.40
f       Fric    front   incor   0.13
f       Fric    back    incor   0.32
f       Fric    front   X       0.08
f       Fric    back    X       0.13
v       Fric    front   NA      0.24
v       Fric    back    NA      0.18
v       Fric    front   cor     0.17
v       Fric    back    cor     0.11
v       Fric    front   incor   0.25
v       Fric    back    incor   0.16
v       Fric    front   X       0.09
v       Fric    back    X       0.16
```

So in total I should get something similar to the grouped data that I have below:

```
                         Front                              Back
pNA pcor pincor cX bNA bcor bincor bX pNA pcor pincor cX bNA bcor bincor bX
         p                    b                    p                    b 
fNA fcor fincor fX vNA vcor vincor vX fNA fcor fincor fX vNA vcor vincor vX
         f                    v                    f                    v
```

I can do some basic filtering of data, and factoring to get certain orders and I know `facet_grid(~Vfront)` gives me different columns according to `Vfront` values (based on my data) but the divisions I am asking about is beyond my current R abilities.

Comment: Do either `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap` come close to giving you what you want?

Comment: That is a bit vague. I know I can do facet_grid(Manner~Vfront) but how do I further separate the Target AND even more specifically, within Target, show the dif MedDor values. That is the part that is beyond me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `ggh4x::facet_nested` for nested facets like you want. If you want a certain order of facets, you need to create `factor` columns with `levels` that you desire; however, `NA` will always come last, so we need to convert `NA` to `"NA"`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(MedDor_f = factor(replace_na(MedDor, "NA") , 
                           levels = c("NA", "cor", "incor", "X")),
         Manner_f = factor(Manner, levels = c("Stop", "Fric")), 
         Vfront_f = factor(Vfront, levels = c("front", "back"))) %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = Target, y = Mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_nested(rows = vars(Manner_f), cols = vars(Vfront_f, MedDor_f))
```

[image]

##### Update:

If you want the x-axis to have a free scale (like what we get in `facet_wrap`), you need to add `scales = "free_x", independent = "x"` to the `facet_nested` function.

<sub>I have also looked at your previous question, and implemented that [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77932418/6461462) here (not sure whether you want that or not, but it looks nice).</sub>

```r
df1 %>% 
  mutate(MedDor_f = factor(replace_na(MedDor, "NA") , 
                           levels = c("NA", "cor", "incor", "X")),
         Manner_f = factor(Manner, levels = c("Stop", "Fric")), 
         Vfront_f = factor(Vfront, levels = c("front", "back")), 
         Deviation = Mean - 0.5) %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = Target, y = Deviation)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Deviation > 0), position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "cadetblue3", "FALSE" = "coral3")) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.5, 0.5),  
                     breaks = seq(-0.5, 0.5, by = 0.1),
                     labels = function(x) sprintf("%.1f", x + 0.5)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  facet_nested(rows = vars(Manner_f), cols = vars(Vfront_f, MedDor_f), 
               scales = "free_x", independent = "x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If you don't want to use `ggh4x`, then you need to use `grid`, `gtable`, and/or `patchwork` or other similar libraries, get your individual plots and arrange them in a grid. I personally would spend some more time on figuring out why `ggh4x` is not working, maybe updating my R version, etc., before going down that route. Good luck!

Comment: Is there another way to write this code without facet_nested(). The ggh4x package is not cooperating and so facet_nested is not working.

Comment: Is it possible to get p and b  and f and v separated without seeing
p b t and v under each MedDor like your sample solution shows.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I am looking for! Unfortunately, I cannot get your code working myself. I precalculated the means before posting my question. I have to also include error bars so I was trying to make the appropriate modifications to run your code, while also trying to implement the error bars but I wasn't successful.

Comment: @heatheryawney have you been able to get this to work for the sample data that you have provided here? If so, then I'd suggest posting another question with a sample data that would represent your current issues with this code. I will take a look at that if you leave a comment here after posting. Cheers.

Comment: I took a break from R stuff because I was incredibly stressed out with everything. I don't think I was thinking completely straight but after a break I now having it working. Thanks so much for the help!!!!!